# QSortFilterProxyModel does not apply Caseinsensitive

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6, qsortfilterproxymodel

As I've subclassed QSortFilterModel to be able to search thru several coloumns in a QListView, the CaseInsensitive option no longer works. Ive tried to apply it as follows:

```
class CustomSortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomSortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.filterString = ''
        self.filterFunctions = {} 
        self.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive) #Applied here



    def setFilterString(self, text):

        self.filterString = str(text)
        self.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)    #And applied here
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row_num, parent):

        self.filterColumns = [1,3]    
        model = self.sourceModel()  
        row = model.row(row_num)
        tests = [self.filterString in row[col] for col in self.filterColumns]

        return True in tests
```

How come my search string is case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensitivity you set there only applies to the default `filterAcceptsRow` implementation. If you override it, you'll need to handle this yourself, by doing something like:

```
return any(self.filterString.casefold() in row[col].casefold() for col in self.filterColumns))
```

(see the [str.casefold docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold))