# Can QCompleter's list of values be modified/updated later again in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I am making a GUI using Pyqt5 where there are 5 Qlineedit fields.

The range of values for each can be say [1 -5]. If the user tried to select third Qlineedit field and selected the value '2'. The other fields range should now **not** include '2' in it.

Similarly if he selected another field with value '4', the remaining fields should have only [1, 3, 5] as available options.

(Please bear in mind that user can delete the value in any field too and available values should be updated accordingly.)

I tried to use list and update QCompleter for the fields as soon as I see any textChanged signal.

The below code works perfectly except when the user lets say had given the input '14' in some field before and now tries to delete it using backspace. '4' will get deleted but on deleting '1' it will crash without any backtrace.

"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

If I click on the lineedit field before deleting '1', it works fine.

Minimal code -

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import sys
import traceback
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QApplication, QCompleter

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.names = ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
        self.names.sort()
        self.line_edits_list = [0]*5

        for i in range(len(self.names)):
            self.line_edits_list[i] = QLineEdit(self)
            completer = QCompleter(self.names, self.line_edits_list[i])
            self.line_edits_list[i].setCompleter(completer)
            vbox.addWidget(self.line_edits_list[i])
            self.line_edits_list[i].textEdited.connect(self.text_changed)

    def text_changed(self, text):
        names_sel = []
        # Check if current text matches anything in our list, if it does add it to a new list
        for i in range(len(self.line_edits_list)):
            if self.line_edits_list[i].text() in self.names and self.line_edits_list[i].text() not in names_sel:
                names_sel.append(self.line_edits_list[i].text())

        # The remaining textfields should get their qcompleter ranges updated with unique values of the two lists
        for i in range(len(self.line_edits_list)):
            if self.line_edits_list[i].text() not in self.names:
                try:
                    new_range = list((set(self.names) - set(names_sel)))
                    completer = QCompleter(new_range, self.line_edits_list[i])
                    self.line_edits_list[i].setCompleter(completer)
                except:
                    print(traceback.format_exc())


def test():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
    print("END")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Why is a QLineEdit necessary? The bad thing with the QLineEdit is that it allows the user to supply other values. Can you use another widget like QComboboxes?

Comment: @eyllanesc I discussed with my peer and he said that we would need QlineEdit as it has 1) auto suggestion facility and also allows us to 2) paste values directly. The possible values or the number of the list names can be big with values like "aabcd_12_sd_fgh" , "aabcd_45_rt_jk". Thus in such scenario 1) and 2) really helps

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in the comments, using QLineEdit is not a suitable widget if you want to restrict the values that the user can select. In this case, as the user has multiple options, then a suitable widget is the QComboBox. To do the filtering you can use QSortFilterProxyModel overriding the filterAcceptsRow method to implement custom logic.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class ProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._hide_items = []

    @property
    def hide_items(self):
        return self._hide_items

    @hide_items.setter
    def hide_items(self, items):
        self._hide_items = items
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        return index.data() not in self.hide_items


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, names, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._comboboxes = []

        model = QStandardItemModel()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        for name in names:
            model.appendRow(QStandardItem(name))
            proxy_model = ProxyModel()
            proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
            combobox = QComboBox()
            combobox.setModel(proxy_model)
            vbox.addWidget(combobox)
            combobox.setCurrentIndex(-1)
            combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.handle_currentIndexChanged)
            self.comboboxes.append(combobox)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @property
    def comboboxes(self):
        return self._comboboxes

    def handle_currentIndexChanged(self):
        rows = []
        for combobox in self.comboboxes:
            if combobox.currentIndex() != -1:
                rows.append(combobox.currentText())

        for i, combobox in enumerate(self.comboboxes):
            index = combobox.currentIndex()
            proxy_model = combobox.model()
            r = rows[:]
            if index != -1:
                text = combobox.currentText()
                if text in r:
                    r.remove(text)
            combobox.blockSignals(True)
            proxy_model.hide_items = r
            combobox.blockSignals(False)


def test():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    names = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

    w = MyWidget(names)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Thanks for the help and introducing me to a completely new thing!
On running your code, it crashes if I change values.  
In the first field select 11, second field select 12, third field select 13, fourth field select 14.
Now change second field to 15 and you should see a crash.

r.remove(combobox.currentText())
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: @AbhinavSaini try again

Comment: Can you please explain how blocking signals helped here when we are not pressing multiple keys or selecting values quickly. So why did we need to wrap hide_items with blockSignals() ?

Comment: I discussed with my peer and he said that we would need QlineEdit as it has 1) auto suggestion facility and also allows us to 2) paste values directly.   The possible values or the number of the list names can be big with values like "aabcd_12_sd_fgh" , "aabcd_45_rt_jk".   Thus in such scenario  1) and 2) really helps.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this is by using a model with the QCompleter. The model can change its content over time and the completer will react to it accordingly.

In your case, you could create a model that contains all possible values first. Then, you could use a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, which, given you current UI state, could reduce the set. The proxy model is the one that you use with `QCompleter`.

This (otherwise unrelated) question is example Python code for implementing such a proxy model: [QSortFilterProxyModel does not apply Caseinsensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291183/qsortfilterproxymodel-does-not-apply-caseinsensitive)

Comment: I could not convert that example link to what I need.          
Can you please help me out here with example code for below points - 
" you could create a model that contains all possible values first." 
 "The proxy model is the one that you use with QCompleter."

Comment: I'm sorry my answer is far from perfect in that regard, however the answer from @eyllanesc provides an implementation that encompasses what I suggest here.

Comment: Yes his answer is good but I need to use Qlineedit and not checkboxes as the user would want to paste the values and checkboxes doesnt support it.   I tried to convert eyllanesc code for Qlineedit but could not do so.

Comment: Yes it is doable with QLineEdit. I don't have the time to write it for you, though.